# How to prevent possible RC

Tags: tarantool

Im using Tarantool 1.5 and lua procedures.

Documentation says a lua procedure can yield execution to another after network/io operation for example, a **box.update** call.

My main question is: if I get return tuple from **box.update** does it contain information "after update, before yield" or "after update, after yield" ?

Also, what is the best-practices to prevent possible race conditions?

Comment: After update, before yield. In 1.6, the best practice against race is using transactions. In 1.5, you have to understand how the scheduler works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do something like a transaction in 1.5, you may do either idempotent operation or do re-select and checks after any yield operation (update/delete/replace)